# Anything similar to MBeans in .NET world?

Tags: c#, .net

Java provides monitoring API using MBeans which is quite handy. Anything similar in .Net world?

Comment: Does [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html) describe the MBeans you are talking about?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not at all familiar with MBeans, but from [this description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/index.html):

> An MBean is a managed Java object, similar to a JavaBeans component, that follows the design patterns set forth in the JMX specification. An MBean can represent a device, an application, or any resource that needs to be managed. MBeans expose a management interface that consists of the following:
>
> - A set of readable or writable attributes, or both.
> - A set of invokable operations.
> - A self-description.

I guess that could be twisted to sound like [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) or [MAF (System.Addins)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020.aspx) maybe. It would probably help to understand better *how* you would expect to use an MBean equivalent in .NET. Understanding the use case would probably make this much easier to answer.

Just stumbled onto [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24160/NetMX-a-JMX-port-to-the-NET-world) rather dated CodeProject project which aims to port that functionality over. Maybe it can be used as a decent starting point?

Answer (score 0):

MEF and MAF are closer to DI (dependency injection) in my mind. Consider the purpose of MBeans, I'd almost consider WMI to be a closer analogue, even though it's not purely a .NET thing.